# Google Sheets, IF, AND, REGEXMATCH, DATE combined Formula

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
IF
    Cells B5:B6 and B8:B9 contains ☑
AND
    Todays date is less than 7 days after the date defined in cell B2
THEN
    In the cell the formula is added write 'On Time' otherwise write 'Behind'
```

I have tried the following formula however it returns a 'Formula parse error'

```
=IF(AND((REGEXMATCH((B5:B6,B8:B9), "☑")),(B2+7) < today() ), 'On Time', 'Running Behind')
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality?

**Edit**

From testing, it seems the issue lies with `REGEXMATCH` not being able to check 2 different cells in the way I've to define it.

May need to use `ArrayFormula(--` from some research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=IF((REGEXMATCH(JOIN("", B5:B6, B8:B9), "☑"))*
 ((B2+7) < TODAY() ), "On Time", "Running Behind")
```

[image: 0]